# Confirmation request on conditional expectation

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $p_1$ and $p_0$ be two probability density functions and let the function defined by $$l(y)=\frac{p_1(y)}{p_0(y)}$$ be the probability ratio function.

$$\int_{\{y:\,l(y)\leq t\}} l(y)p_0(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=E_{P_0}[l(Y)\mid l\leq t]$$

I wrote this when I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308176/writing-the-conditional-expectation-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable-in-a-diff) and I think this equality is wrong. I have just realized it because there is no normalization.

In other words, I have another equation:

$$\frac{1}{P_0[a\leq l(Y)\leq b]}\int_{a\leq l(y)\leq b} l(y) p_0(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = E_{P_0}[l(Y)\mid a\leq l\leq b] $$

which seems to me correct, beacause there is normalization. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed, for every measurable $B$ such that $P_0(\ell(Y)\in B)\ne0$, $$\int_{\{y\mid\ell(y)\in B\}}\ell(y)p_0(y)dy=E_0(\ell(Y)\mathbf 1_{\ell(Y)\in B})=E_0(\ell(Y)\mid\ell(Y)\in B)P_0(\ell(Y)\in B).$$

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for the reply. I am sometimes confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the conditional density of $Y$, given that $a \le \ell(Y) \le b,$ equal to $\dfrac {p_0(y)}{\Pr(a \le \ell(Y) \le b)}\text {?}$ If so, then the proposed answer is right.

\begin{align}
& \Pr(Y \in A\mid a\le\ell(Y)\le b) = \frac{\Pr(Y \in A\ \&\ a \le \ell(Y) \le b)}{\Pr(a\le\ell(Y)\le b)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{ \  \displaystyle \int\limits_{A \, \cap \, \{y \, :\, a\le\ell(y)\le b\}} p_0(y) \, \mathrm{d}y\  }{\Pr(a\le\ell(Y)\le b)} = \int\limits_{A \, \cap \, \{y \, :\, a\le\ell(y)\le b\}} \frac{p_0(y)}{\Pr(a\le \ell(y) \le b)} \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align}
The fact that a particular function $f$ satisfies
$$
\Pr(Y\in A \mid Y\in B) = \int\limits_{A\,\cap\,B} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
for **all** measurable sets $A$ into which $Y$ could fall, is just what it means to say that $f$ is the conditional density given that $Y\in B$.

Thus the proposed answer is right.